# How to control TeeChart's Series marks position?

Tags: delphi-xe2, firemonkey, teechart

I want to draw marks in custom positions, but what is the best event or procedure for it? 
Because if I process them in OnAfterDraw event my chart will be rendered twice and etc.
Is it possible to set the position before drawing the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the series to have been drawn at least once (so its marks' positions have been populated) to be able to modify these positions.